# ocaml - function without args and global variables

Tags: variables, ocaml, global

I have a task to do in ocaml and can't find any help information so ask here ;) How to define function which give us something other in each call without using global variables ? I would like to do fun next() which return next odd numbers or next values of factorial.

Like this

```
# next();;
- : int = 1
# next();;
- : int = 3
# next();;
- : int = 5
# next();;
- : int = 7
```

Do you have any tips for me ?

Thanks in advance

Greg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let next =
  let private_counter = ref (-1) in
  fun () ->
    private_counter := !private_counter + 2;
    !private_counter
```

You can also encapsulate this in a "counter factory":

```
let make_counter () =
  (* note the () parameter : at each call of make_counter(),
     a new "next function" with a fresh counter is generated *)
  let private_counter = ...
```

Comment: Funny, it's the kind of question I ask in interviews :)

Comment: One more question ;) How to encapsulate next ? I'm trying to add make_counter but have syntax error, how should it looks ?

Comment: really it's the code I gave : `let make_counter () = let private_counter = ... in fun () -> ...`. You should be able to write it without error. I think it will be better for you if you find it out yourself rather than getting the full solution here.